# phpmyadmin prefixes a number to the existing numbers of certain columns in certain tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Sorry for the difficult description, but I know of no better way to say it.

When I look in certain tables of a MySQL database through the phpMyAdmin web interface, the numbers of the first two columns are prefixed by a '3'.

So if the first column has number 99, phpMyAdmin displays 3939.

The second column has number 3592, phpMyAdmin shows 33353932.

If I check the records with the `mysql` CLI they are displayed correctly.

It only happens to some columns in some tables of some databases... not to all.

So it might be something with the tables themselves or something with phpMyAdmin.

System/version info:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- phpmyadmin 4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2
- apache2 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5
- php7.0 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- oracle-java9 9.0.1-1~webupd8~0
- mysql-server 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

I'm hoping someone has some idea of what might be happening here.

If you wish any further clarification please let me know.

mysql CLI:

```
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_gsb                |
+------------------------------+
| gsb_challenge                |
| gsb_challenge_pos            |
| gsb_challenge_scope          |
| gsb_copyright                |
| gsb_correction               |
| gsb_correction_gold          |
| gsb_correction_literality    |
| gsb_correction_sentalign     |
| gsb_correction_tag           |
| gsb_correction_tokenization  |
| gsb_correction_wordalign     |
| gsb_doc_counts               |
| gsb_doc_status               |
| gsb_doc_warnings             |
| gsb_documents                |
| gsb_log                      |
| gsb_reports_verbnet          |
| gsb_semlex_entry             |
| gsb_semlex_entry_cooc_cat    |
| gsb_semlex_entry_cooc_lemma  |
| gsb_semlex_entry_cooc_ne     |
| gsb_semlex_entry_cooc_pos    |
| gsb_semlex_entry_cooc_roles  |
| gsb_semlex_entry_name        |
| gsb_semlex_occurrence        |
| gsb_status_flag              |
| gsb_subcorpus                |
| gsb_synsets                  |
| gsb_user                     |
| gsb_userCake_Groups          |
| gsb_userCake_Users           |
| gsb_v_accepted_docs          |
| gsb_v_last_doc_status        |
| gsb_v_last_doc_update        |
| pmb_annotation_status        |
| pmb_correction               |
| pmb_correction_sentalign     |
| pmb_correction_tag           |
| pmb_correction_tokenization  |
| pmb_dmatch                   |
| pmb_doc_counts               |
| pmb_doc_lists                |
| pmb_doc_status               |
| pmb_doc_warnings             |
| pmb_documents                |
| pmb_lrec                     |
| pmb_lrec_dmatch              |
| pmb_lrec_dmatch_backup       |
| pmb_lrec_promatch            |
| pmb_promatch                 |
| pmb_promatch_copy            |
| pmb_reports_verbnet          |
| pmb_semlex_entry             |
| pmb_semlex_entry_cooc_cat    |
| pmb_semlex_entry_cooc_lemma  |
| pmb_semlex_entry_cooc_pos    |
| pmb_semlex_entry_cooc_roles  |
| pmb_semlex_entry_cooc_semtag |
| pmb_semlex_occurrence        |
| pmb_status_flag              |
| pmb_subcorpus                |
| pmb_synsets                  |
| pmb_synsets_new              |
| pmb_userCake_Groups          |
| pmb_userCake_Users           |
| pmb_v_phrase_search          |
+------------------------------+

SELECT * FROM pmb_semlex_occurrence ORDER BY part DESC LIMIT 10;
+------+--------+-------+------+------+--------+------+----------------+------+----+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+
| part | doc_id | tokid | from | to   | toknum | snum | cat            | pos  | ne | roles     | wordnet | wordsense | semtag | lemma  | token  | token_lc | entry_id                         |
+------+--------+-------+------+------+--------+------+----------------+------+----+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+
| 99   | 3592   | 15056 | 2202 | 2203 |    453 |   15 | (N/PP)\(N/PP)  | LQU  |    | []        | O       | O         | NIL    | "      | "      | "        | 594f1919d740100ed2f3e4cfd4100329 |
| 99   | 3592   | 15055 | 2201 | 2202 |    452 |   15 | (N/PP)\(N/PP)  | .    |    | []        | O       | O         | NIL    | .      | .      | .        | 594f1919d740100ed2f3e4cfd4100329 |
```

phpmyadmin:

[image: What phpmyadmin shows]

[image: When you click edit on a record]

It's not my database, I only maintain the server it's running on, so I don't think it's a prank... and how would they even do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a screenshot as well as table definitions for affected tables.

Comment: This sounds like a prank from a colleague

Comment: show details of an affected table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information that these columns are of `BINARY` type I was able to find two bug reports describing this behaviour:

- [broken view of binary fields (every second three)](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/10554)
- [broken link to table of binary fields (every second three)](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13387)

The first should have been resolved in phpMyAdmin 4.3, but I see that you're using version 4.5. The related second issue was reported against version 4.7.1 and fixed in version 4.7.3.

Try upgrading to phpMyAdmin 4.7.3 or later (at the time of writing the latest version is 4.7.7).

Comment: I was using the stable packaged version provided by Ubuntu (xenial), they don't go farther then 4.5, so I downloaded the latest and installed it manually. That seems to have solved the problem, according to the database users. Thank you.